# unable to send logrus output /dev/null

Tags: logging, go

I'm using [Logrus](https://github.com/sirupsen/logrus) package for logging on my project.

All is fine but for testing purpose I do not need the logrus output to be displayed.

I looking at `logrus.SetOuput` for answer.

So basically I want the log to be written to `/dev/null`

But for some reason I still see the logs on STDOUT

```
   // This code run right at the start
   if env == "test" {
        fmt.Println("Entering test mode ....")
        logrus.SetOutput(ioutil.Discard)
        return
    }
```

Here how my logger setup looks like

```
// logger.go

package logger

import(
    "os"
    "io/ioutil"
    "github.com/Sirupsen/logrus"
)

var log *logrus.Logger

const (
    DEBUG   = 0
    INFO    = 1
    WARNING = 2
    ERROR   = 3
)

func init() {
    env := os.GetEnv("ENV")
    if env != "test" {
        return
    }
    logrus.SetOutput(ioutil.Discard)
}


func Init(logLevl int) {
    log = logrus.New()
    log.Formatter = &logrus.TextFormatter{FullTimestamp: true}
    switch logLevl {
    case DEBUG:
        log.Level = logrus.DebugLevel
    case INFO:
        log.Level = logrus.InfoLevel
    case WARNING:
        log.Level = logrus.WarnLevel
    case ERROR:
        log.Level = logrus.ErrorLevel
    }
}

func Get() *logrus.Logger {
    return log
}

func I(args ...interface{}) {
    log.Info(args)
}

func Df(format string, args ...interface{}) {
    log.Debugf(format, args)
}

func D(args ...interface{}) {
    log.Debug(args)
}

func W(args ...interface{}) {
    log.Warn(args)
}
```

And here how I use the `logger` package

```
import "logger"

func init() {
  logger.Init(0)
}

logger.D("Dummy string")
```

Comment: @mattn SetOutput() on package level configures the exported std logger of logrus (c.f., https://github.com/sirupsen/logrus/blob/master/exported.go)

Comment: @fhe If talking new variable via New(), and modify with logrus.SetOutput() (i.e. std), it can be different behavior, I think. Or get &Logger{}.

Comment: @mattn Hope this help .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using two different `logrus.Logger` variables in your code. The first, which is called in `init()` is the global default Logger that gets exported from logrus. Later, in your custom initialization function `Init(logLevel int)`, you're creating a new Logger via `logrus.New()` which is from then on used for logging — but hasn't been configured to use a different output.

I'd suggest to get rid of the init() function and do all the initialization in your `Init(logLevel int)` (please note the different API for setting the output).

```
func Init(logLevl int) {
    log = logrus.New()
    log.Formatter = &logrus.TextFormatter{FullTimestamp: true}
    switch logLevl {
    case DEBUG:
        log.Level = logrus.DebugLevel
    case INFO:
        log.Level = logrus.InfoLevel
    case WARNING:
        log.Level = logrus.WarnLevel
    case ERROR:
        log.Level = logrus.ErrorLevel
    }

    env := os.Getenv("ENV")
    if env != "test" {
        return
    }
    log.Out = ioutil.Discard
}
```